# Initialize a Select Submodule in git rather then all of them

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a common submodule across many projects which is designed to be build on many difference platforms. Since I maintain the code for the core logic and the interfaces from the different platforms, I have submodules for each to keep track and have the code build against all the platforms like so:

```
lib/core_logic_module/lib/
                         platform_1
                         platform_2
                         ...
                         platform_X
```

When working on a project that requires a specif platform, it is very nice to actually have the platform specific module so changes can be examined if needed and not the unneeded ones. Do a plane old `git submodule update --init --recursive` clones all the submodules and their specif dependencies which makes using `grep`, `ctags`, and `find` a pain as the platforms all have similar files for hardware abstraction.

Is there a simple way when initializing submodules to specify that I only want a single module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one or more paths with `git submodule update`.
As from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), you can do this:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive <path>...
```

A few additional details about `<path>...`:

> Paths to submodule(s). When specified this will restrict the command to only operate on the submodules found at the specified paths. (This argument is required with add).